# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu Content to slide left

Tags: animation, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am using a bootstrap Dropdown Menu and I want to slide (animate) content of the dropdown to the left and bring a new content. This is similar to google email option, after logged in you can click on the picture and dropdown shows up with all latest messages and you can click on the first one and it slides it and shows the content for that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? (It's always a good idea to provide some code illustrating what you've attempted, otherwise it just looks like you're asking people to do all the work for you.)

Comment: @middaparka agree with you, and user2363228 please add some code or show your work using jsfiddle.

Comment: My sincere apologize for not showing my code, here is code example which shows what I am trying to achieve...please pardon my limited knowledge on JQ http://jsfiddle.net/JeganJSFiddle/tKauh/59/